# PHP mysql query judge and not echo the repeart part

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a php search query. First, I put a sentence and explode every word get `$name`,Then I put `$name` make a query to match all the name which is exist in my database.  Then echo part `$row['name'][$i]` has some word repeat.

for example: the sentence is :`Marc Gasol is the brother of Pau Gasol` and `Gasol` in my database, so the match words `Gasol` apearl 2 times. how to `echo $row['name'][$i];` and get only one  `Gasol`? thanks,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE name like '$name[0]' OR name like '$name[1]' OR name like '$name[2]' OR name like '$name[3]' "); 
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {     
echo $row['name'][$i];     
$i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sentence = "Marc Gasol is the brother of Pau Gasol";
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $sentence);

//this will uniqueify your value set
$uniqueWords = array_keys(array_flip($words));

foreach($uniqueWords as $word){
    $parts[] = "name like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($word)."%'";  
}

$where = implode(" OR ", $parts);




$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE $where "); 
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {     
echo $row['name'][$i];     
$i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run another quick loop through your array and remove all duplicate words before you proceed to executing your sql query that way you don't search the name twice in the first place. That should work if I am understanding what you are wanting to do.