# php select from where and problem

Tags: php, mysql

```
$name1 = @$_GET['search'] ;
$name = split(" +",$name1);
$query = "select * from table where field1 = '".$name[0]."'
and field2 = '".$name[1]."'
Order By `date` DESC";
```

I make a easy search like that, but if  `$name[0]` and `$name[1]` all have data, the query can work, and if  `$name[1]` is empty, the query is failed. how to add a judge that if `$name[1]` is empty, hidden `and field2 = '".$name[1]."'`, and  make the query like

`$query = "select * from table where field1 = '".$name[0]."' Order By`date`DESC";`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mysql query judge and not echo the repeart part.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085180/php-mysql-query-judge-and-not-echo-the-repeart-part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 if(!empty($name[0]) or !empty($name[1])){
    $sql = "select * from table where ";

    if($name[0]){
       $fld1 = " field1 = '".$name[0]."'";           
    }
    if($name[1]){
       $fld2 = " field2 = '".$name[1]."'";           
    }

    if($fld1 && $fld2)
    {
        $sql .= $fld1 ." and ".$fld2;
    }
    elseif($fld1){
        $sql .= $fld1;
    }
    elseif($fld2){
        $sql .= $fld2;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with an `or`:

```
(and field2 = '".$name[1]."' or '".$name[1]."' = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you in your PHP script, do this check like this

```
$query = "select * from table where field1 = '$name[0]'"
if ($name[1]) $query .= " and field2 = '$name[1]'";
$query .= 'order by date desc';
```

Comment: what if there will be 3 parts?

Comment: I write simple part, if there will be 3 parts I can write some function joinAnd() and use it

Answer (score 0):

```
$name[1]?'query of it exists':'query if it doesn't';
```